# Can't get strings from table

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is I'm trying to extract all the text strings from the table inside this div element.

There only a few strings I would like to extract for a example. "SoreTruchman".
This string can be found under the `<tr data-player-ref="2">` This is one of the strings I would like to extract. All of the strings I would like to extract are under the HTML `<tr data-player-ref="SOMENUMBER">`. There can be multiple of these. A random number of `<tr data-player-ref="somenum">` Under these elements. I need those strings only so I can simply just log them.

Here's a HTML example, containing a string I would like to extract. (Part of the TABLE!)

```
<tr data-player-ref="2">
        <td>SoreTruchman
            <br>
        </td>
```

All of the strings right under the "data-player-ref" elements. One string example would equal "SoreTruchman".

I've tried a lot.  You can see one example of what I've tried inside my script below.
here's my script:

```
var Row = document.getElementById("team_players");
var Table = Row.getElementsByTagName("table");
var Tbody = Table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var tr = Tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
var td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
console.log(td[0].innerText)
```

This gives me a error. I'm not sure why. I tried to add all of the elements to root to the text path, but no luck..

Can someone help me extract the text from this html?

```html
<div id="team_players">
<h3>Players</h3>
<button class="bold-btn" onclick="teamAct('player_list');">Refresh List ↻</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name(s)</th>
            <th>Inventory</th>
            <th>Playtime</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-player-ref="1">
            <td>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>☘️Ｂ۩ＮＫ☘️
                <br>☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️
                <br>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>43:45:44</td>
            <td><u style="color: #0F0">Online</u><u style="color: #0FF">Captain [1]</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of SoreTruchman &lt;0&gt;</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of lol &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-player-ref="2">
            <td>SoreTruchman
                <br>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5:03</td>
            <td><u style="color: #888">Offline</u><u style="color: #FF0">Crew</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of ☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️ &lt;0&gt;</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of lol &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn-small" onclick="teamAct('rank_guest',2);">Make Guest</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-blue" onclick="teamAct('rank_captain',2);">Make Captain</button>
                <br>
                <button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('kick',2);">Kick</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-red" onclick="teamAct('ban',2);">Ban</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-player-ref="3">
            <td>lol
                <br>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5:00</td>
            <td><u style="color: #888">Offline</u><u style="color: #FF0">Crew</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of ☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️ &lt;0&gt;</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of SoreTruchman &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn-small" onclick="teamAct('rank_guest',3);">Make Guest</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-blue" onclick="teamAct('rank_captain',3);">Make Captain</button>
                <br>
                <button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('kick',3);">Kick</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-red" onclick="teamAct('ban',3);">Ban</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Maybe with mutations-observer?? Thank you.

Comment: `Table.getElementsByTagName` doesn’t exist. `Table` isn’t an `Element`. It may be easier to work with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` to find all the player rows in the table directly.
Then you can map over either the innerHTML or the textContent.

I preferred using the innerHTML here, since that allows us to split on the 
 break tags to extract only the first name. ( Or make the full list if needed. )

If we use the textContent, we would have to split on whitespace characters, which could cause trouble if you allow names with spaces.

ps: if possible, always prefer grabbing the data out of some variable instead of scraping HTML tags for text.
Since `teamAct()` events are written inline, teamAct() is probably a global. So there might be a global variable holding the names as well.

pps: Can we cheat by calling `teamAct('kick', someID )` in the console?

```js
const player_references = document.querySelectorAll( '#team_players tr[data-player-ref]' );

const players = Array
  .from( player_references )
  .map( row => {
    const id = row.getAttribute( 'data-player-ref' );
    // since there are #text nodes between <tr> and the first <td>
    // we cannot actually use .firstChild, since it's not the <td>
    // so we use querySelector again to avoid also counting the #text nodes.
    const name = row
      .querySelector( 'td:first-child' )
      .innerHTML
      .split( '<br>' )[0]
      .trim();
    return { id, name };
  });
  
console.log( players );
```

```html
<div id="team_players">
<h3>Players</h3>
<button class="bold-btn" onclick="teamAct('player_list');">Refresh List ↻</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name(s)</th>
            <th>Inventory</th>
            <th>Playtime</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-player-ref="1">
            <td>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>☘️Ｂ۩ＮＫ☘️
                <br>☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️
                <br>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>43:45:44</td>
            <td><u style="color: #0F0">Online</u><u style="color: #0FF">Captain [1]</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of SoreTruchman &lt;0&gt;</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of lol &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-player-ref="2">
            <td>SoreTruchman
                <br>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5:03</td>
            <td><u style="color: #888">Offline</u><u style="color: #FF0">Crew</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of ☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️ &lt;0&gt;</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of lol &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn-small" onclick="teamAct('rank_guest',2);">Make Guest</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-blue" onclick="teamAct('rank_captain',2);">Make Captain</button>
                <br>
                <button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('kick',2);">Kick</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-red" onclick="teamAct('ban',2);">Ban</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-player-ref="3">
            <td>lol
                <br>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5:00</td>
            <td><u style="color: #888">Offline</u><u style="color: #FF0">Crew</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of ☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️ &lt;0&gt;</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of SoreTruchman &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn-small" onclick="teamAct('rank_guest',3);">Make Guest</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-blue" onclick="teamAct('rank_captain',3);">Make Captain</button>
                <br>
                <button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('kick',3);">Kick</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-red" onclick="teamAct('ban',3);">Ban</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a champ. Anyway I could grab the ``data-player-ref`` value of that current string that's being logged? So when it logs the "SoreTruchman", it will log the ``data-player-ref`` value of that string's parent?  Which is "2".

Comment: I have updated my code. Instead of directly selecting the first cells, we select the row instead and find the first `<td>` inside the `.map()`. ( We could reverse this and look at the `.parentNode` instead ) Then we can use `.getAttribute()` to get the id value. I'm returning an object here for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it here instead. 
So this uses querySelectorAll to find all of the `tr` that has the attribute `data-player-ref` and extracts the text of the first `td`

```js
var test = document.querySelectorAll('tr[data-player-ref] > td:first-of-type');
test.forEach(myFunction)

function myFunction(item, index) {
  
  console.log(item.innerText); //The entire name with all html
  console.log(item.innerHTML.split( '<br>' )[0].trim()); //only the first line
  console.log(item.parentElement.getAttribute("data-player-ref")); //the value of the data-player-ref attribute
}
```

```html
<div id="team_players">
<h3>Players</h3>
<button class="bold-btn" onclick="teamAct('player_list');">Refresh List ↻</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name(s)</th>
            <th>Inventory</th>
            <th>Playtime</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-player-ref="1">
            <td>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>Lol
                <br>☘️Ｂ۩ＮＫ☘️
                <br>☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️
                <br>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>43:45:44</td>
            <td><u style="color: #0F0">Online</u><u style="color: #0FF">Captain [1]</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of SoreTruchman &lt;0&gt;</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of lol &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
            <td>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-player-ref="2">
            <td>SoreTruchman
                <br>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5:03</td>
            <td><u style="color: #888">Offline</u><u style="color: #FF0">Crew</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of ☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️ &lt;0&gt;</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of lol &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn-small" onclick="teamAct('rank_guest',2);">Make Guest</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-blue" onclick="teamAct('rank_captain',2);">Make Captain</button>
                <br>
                <button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('kick',2);">Kick</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-red" onclick="teamAct('ban',2);">Ban</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-player-ref="3">
            <td>lol
                <br>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5:00</td>
            <td><u style="color: #888">Offline</u><u style="color: #FF0">Crew</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of ☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️ &lt;0&gt;</u>
                <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of SoreTruchman &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn-small" onclick="teamAct('rank_guest',3);">Make Guest</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-blue" onclick="teamAct('rank_captain',3);">Make Captain</button>
                <br>
                <button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('kick',3);">Kick</button>
                <button class="btn-small btn-red" onclick="teamAct('ban',3);">Ban</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great. Anyway I could make it only log the names once? I don't need the strings next to the ``<br>`` Anyway I could bypass these and only get the first strings? So it will only print "Lol" once, just like the SoreTruchman.

Comment: @Nestly - sure, then you would just use `console.log(item.innerHTML.split( '<br>' )[0].trim());` instead like Shilly did in his answer

Comment: Anyway I could log the data-player-ref value of that string? So I could use that data-player-ref value of that string as a variable? This will be my last question. I thank you.

Comment: Please. Your reply is  easier to work with. The others seems complicated and hard to work with. I'm not that good with JavaScript yet. Your reply is the easiest for me so far. Please help me out a bit.

Comment: @Nestly - I added some code in the console.log part, for you to get the attribute value

Answer (score 0):

Add e.g. `class='name'` to `<td>` you want to get string from. Then use `querySelectorAll` to retrive `textContent` from every `<td class='name'>` in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to incorrectly access the innerHTML. The line

```
Row.getElementsByTagName("table")
```

returns a HTMLCollection and NOT a HTML Element. Hence, you should be getting an error:

> Table.getElementsByTagName doesn’t exist

Better way of implementation could be to give ID to your tr.

```js
function teamAct(setterValue, index) {
  var row = document.getElementsByTagName("tr").namedItem(index);
  row.querySelector("td").innerText = setterValue;
}
```

```html
<div id="team_players">
  <h3>Players</h3>
  <button class="bold-btn" onclick="teamAct('player_list');">Refresh List ↻</button>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name(s)</th>
        <th>Inventory</th>
        <th>Playtime</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="1">
        <td>Lol
          <br>Lol
          <br>Lol
          <br>Lol
          <br>Lol
          <br>☘️Ｂ۩ＮＫ☘️
          <br>☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️
          <br>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>43:45:44</td>
        <td><u style="color: #0F0">Online</u><u style="color: #0FF">Captain [1]</u>
          <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of SoreTruchman &lt;0&gt;</u>
          <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of lol &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
        <td>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="2">
        <td>SoreTruchman
          <br>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>5:03</td>
        <td><u style="color: #888">Offline</u><u style="color: #FF0">Crew</u>
          <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of ☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️ &lt;0&gt;</u>
          <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of lol &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn-small" onclick="teamAct('rank_guest',2);">Make Guest</button>
          <button class="btn-small btn-blue" onclick="teamAct('rank_captain',2);">Make Captain</button>
          <br>
          <button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('kick',2);">Kick</button>
          <button class="btn-small btn-red" onclick="teamAct('ban',2);">Ban</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="3">
        <td>lol
          <br>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>5:00</td>
        <td><u style="color: #888">Offline</u><u style="color: #FF0">Crew</u>
          <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of ☘️Ｂ☘ＮＫ☘️ &lt;0&gt;</u>
          <br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of SoreTruchman &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn-small" onclick="teamAct('rank_guest',3);">Make Guest</button>
          <button class="btn-small btn-blue" onclick="teamAct('rank_captain',3);">Make Captain</button>
          <br>
          <button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('kick',3);">Kick</button>
          <button class="btn-small btn-red" onclick="teamAct('ban',3);">Ban</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```